# How to launch a fragment within a ViewPager from an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-viewpager

Apologies in advance, if there is a similar question to this that has already been answered. However, I have tried all possible solutions and have failed.

Right so I am creating an app , which contains three fragments within a `ViewPager`, which is set in the main `Activity`. Meaning that when I execute the android application, it will display the first fragment, and swiping left will display the other fragments.

The problem is, in my Fragment I have a `ListView` and also a `FloatingActionButton`. When the user wants to enter a new entry, they press the button and a new activity launches where they input the data into an `EditText`. (To this point it works)

How do I now relaunch that fragment so that it returns to the fragment and shows the updated `ListView`?

In essence, what is an alternative way of using.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

As that is what I use when dealing with activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to launch a fragment, you must first launch an activity which contains the fragment. There are at least three different ways to return to the ViewPager activity.

1. Use an intent to launch a new instance of the activity. It sounds like you know how to do this.
2. Provide [Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) to allow your user to go back to the original activity with the ViewPager. If your `ListView` is implemented correctly, it will load the data, including the new record.
3. Use [`startActivityForResult()`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?) instead of `startActivity()` to launch the "editing activity". This is handy if you allow the user to edit only a single record.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state of your activity with your fragments in a bundle and recover them on start.

You may also consider [starting the activity for result](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?)